# Django Client and Extranet Users distinction

Tags: django, authentication, privileges

I'm building an App with public access, restricted area for clients and another restricted area for managers.

I have a `Manager` model and `Client` model with foreign key to Users. And Manager is automatically added to group `managers` and client to `clients`.

I have an extranet for client which now is restricted by @login_required. It's same with extranet for managers.

I need to disable access clients to managers extranet.

Is it better creating a privilege in managers group and add it to every view in extranet part or somehow different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `user_passes_test` decorator:

Add this  line before the view which you want to restrict to managers.

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.groups.filter(name='managers').count() > 0, login_url='/myapp/denied/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Als I found a existing decorator for this using **user_passes_test** called **group_required**

Can be found here http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1703/